# Convert mp3 file into URL in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl

I have sound files (mp3 and m4a) that I imported into my xCode project that I need to convert into URLs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [URLForResource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1411540-url):

```
if let audioURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "audioName", withExtension: "mp3") {
    print(audioURL) 
}
```